# How to display partial pending in status column when column contains both pending and completed in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to display partial pending in my status column when status column contains both pending and completed.

**Table:**

```
Enquiry Name    Part Number     Status
------------------------------------------
Enq1            aar-12332       Pending
Enq1            aar-12555       Completed
Enq2            aar-12666       Pending
```

**Expected Result:**

```
Enquiry Name    Status
----------------------------------
Enq1            Partial Pending
Enq2            Pending
```

I wrote and tried many query but I did not get as expected.

Please Help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the approach below, you can achieve your expected result:

```
-- Get 'Partial Pending'
SELECT EnquiryName, 'Partial Pending' AS `Status`
FROM EnquiryTable 
WHERE `Status` IN ('Pending', 'Completed' )  
GROUP BY EnquiryName
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT `Status`) = 2

UNION

-- Get the remaining Status
SELECT EnquiryName, `Status`
FROM EnquiryTable 
WHERE `Status` IN ('Pending', 'Completed' )  
GROUP BY EnquiryName
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT `Status`) <> 2
```

Result:

```
EnquiryName     Status
Enq1            Partial Pending
Enq2            Pending
```

Reference from this [post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/97935/68079)

SQL Fiddle [`DEMO`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c287eb/3) for the same.